# mysql: can't change tmpdir to anything except /tmp

Tags: mysql, innodb, tmp

I create /mysqltmp directory as a root user and give it the same permissions as the /tmp directory (chmod 1777 /mysqltmp). But when I start mysql, service fails to start and I get the following error in logs:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/mysqltmp/ib9AeHFf' (Errcode: 13)
140417  9:46:46  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
140417  9:46:46 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140417  9:46:46 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140417  9:46:46 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140417  9:46:46 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Error 13 is "Permission denied".

MySQL server version is 5.5.35 and OS is Ubuntu 12.04.4.

Comment: Could you please ensure with 'ls -l' that the directory really has the required rights set?

Comment: @FrediWeber,

Yes, they have identical rights.

Comment: The default apparmor profile for mysql in 12.04 forbids writing to arbitrary directories.